# What is a "python" api?

Tags: python, json, rest

There is a website (http://xisbn.worldcat.org/xisbnadmin/doc/api.htm) that offers its API in several formats, including XML, CSV, JSON and something called "python". I am assuming this is related to the Python programming language, but how? The output looks like this:

```
{
 'stat':'ok',
 'list':[{
    'url':['http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/177669176?referer=xid'],
    'publisher':'O\'Reilly',
    'form':['BA',
     'DA'],
    'lccn':['2004273129'],
    'lang':'eng',
    'city':'Sebastopol, CA',
    'author':'by Mark Lutz and David Ascher.',
    'ed':'2nd ed.',
    'year':'2003',
    'isbn':['0596002815'],
    'title':'Learning Python',
    'oclcnum':['177669176',
     '222927677',
     '249274099',
     '253402825',
     '301161087',
     '438280230',
     '442197411',
     '464709193',
     '492988633',
     '54619668',
     '55847258',
     '614957020',
     '644729085',
     '760707144',
     '772683553',
     '802989466',
     '850841661',
     '851226517',
     '875412584']}]}
```

This looks like JSON to me, but the JSON output, while similar, is this:

```
{
 "stat":"ok",
 "list":[{
    "url":["http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/177669176?referer=xid"],
    "publisher":"O'Reilly",
    "form":["BA",
     "DA"],
    "lccn":["2004273129"],
    "lang":"eng",
    "city":"Sebastopol, CA",
    "author":"by Mark Lutz and David Ascher.",
    "ed":"2nd ed.",
    "year":"2003",
    "isbn":["0596002815"],
    "title":"Learning Python",
    "oclcnum":["177669176",
     "222927677",
     "249274099",
     "253402825",
     "301161087",
     "438280230",
     "442197411",
     "464709193",
     "492988633",
     "54619668",
     "55847258",
     "614957020",
     "644729085",
     "760707144",
     "772683553",
     "802989466",
     "850841661",
     "851226517",
     "875412584"]}]}
```

The "python" example doesn't parse as valid JSON, so what is it? How would one decode this information in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Python literal; it uses Python syntax for everything. Python syntax for dictionaries and lists and strings is quite close to the equivalent JSON syntax. The Python strings are *byte strings* however, not Unicode values like they would be in JSON.

Any `null` JSON values will be represented as `None` in Python, and any booleans will be rendered as `True` and `False` rather than the JSON `true` and `false`.

You can parse it with the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but this is going to be slower than parsing JSON. Don't ever be tempted to use `eval()` on such data; all it takes is for the API DNS entry to be hijacked for an attacker to feed you arbitrary Python objects and compromise your process.

Frankly, offering a Python syntax is rather pointless, in my view. They offer PHP and Ruby variants too; all that varies are the delimiters around the types. This is, at best, a curiosity; presumably parsing JSON will be faster in those other languages too (as parsing Python, Ruby or PHP requires support for a lot more types), or opening those processes up for `eval()`-style attacks.

Comment: I guess the benefit of this "python code" is that you can use data structures that are not considered in JSON, like a `set`. Not a huge benefit, actually.

Comment: So what's the point, if JSON is faster? Should I use this, or JSON?

Comment: @ikaros45: I doubt that the API is going to offer any such data structures. The same data needs to be represented in JSON, CSV, Ruby, PHP and HTML too.

Comment: @felixphew: use JSON; I highly doubt that they'll be using any native Python data types that are hard to represent in JSON.

Comment: It's seems like they're encouraging people to `eval()` this stuff (in the language of their choice) rather than using a proper parsing library. Thank goodness for `ast.literal_eval()`, but I bet some people will use vanilla `eval()`...

Comment: @PM2Ring: indeed, at which point they are a poisened DNS step away from total process compromise.

Comment: OTOH, I _suppose_ it could be handy if you want to manually copy & paste it into a script, in which case you can visually verify that it's safe. But I can't think of a scenario where you _would_ want to do that with this sort of data. :)